# What will be the URL Rewriting rule for this?

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I have a static web application on a windows hosting of Godaddy.

In my application I have URLs like below:

```
http://MyDomain.com/?page_id=18
http://MyDomain.com/?page_id=19
http://MyDomain.com/?page_id=20
```

And I want the Rewritten URLs to be like this:

```
http://MyDomain.com/microsoft-cloud-crm-for-small-business
http://MyDomain.com/online-development
http://MyDomain.com/small-development
```

So what will be the URL Rewriting rule in the web.config file..?

**EDIT:**

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
<asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
<rewrite>
    <rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite url" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^\?page_id=18" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="microsoft-cloud-crm-for-small-business" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Rewrite url1">
        <match url="^\?page_id=21" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="Implementation" />
    </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="Rewrite url">
    <match url="^?page_id=18" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="custom-development.html" />
    </rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: You might want to consider using a RewriteMap so you don't need to write out each regex.

Comment: You need to get a detailed error message. See http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/3430/how-do-i-enable-windows-hosting-accounts-to-show-more-detailed-error-messages

Comment: `The expression "^?page_id=18" contains a repeat expression (one of '*', '?', '+', '{' in most contexts) not preceded by an expression.`

Comment: Sorry dude. put a '\' infornt of '?'. '<match url="^\?page_id=18" />'

Comment: Ok..The error is gone...but now nothing happens at all..it doesn't rewritten to http://MyDomain.com/custom-development.html

Comment: Try changing action type to redirect. '<action type="Redirect"  url="custom-development.html" redirectType="Permanent" />'

Comment: can you post your web.config?

Comment: What about the '\' before '?', it not there in that config.

Comment: Ok. could you try using location tag.

Comment: I don't think location tag will work for you since the page_id is passed as a parameter.

Comment: The current web.config is looking good. That should do the trick for you. But i can't really understand y its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Hi actually i am not useing a .html extenssion url Rewriting . i am useing a without extenssion url Rewriting and which url you are  saying i create a rules for that url in my project it's below

```
<add name="test"  virtualUrl="^~/test-page/([0-9,a-z,A-Z,_,-]*)"
  rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
  destinationUrl="~/test.aspx?cid=$1"
  ignoreCase="true" />
```

i think this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

Well If you are using asp.net with .Net version 4.0 you can get benefits of RouteCollection in your web form projects as well.

Using this you can easily map your URL with particular navigation rule.

E.g in your case if "microsoft-cloud-crm-for-small-business" is identical name from any table you can put following code in global.asax...

```
 routes.MapPageRoute(
               "ViewPageDetail",               // Route name
               "/{*CategoryName}",  // Route URL
               "~/PageDetail.aspx"      // Web page to handle route
            );
```

And then in your page load you can have something like following.

```
string productName = Page.RouteData.Values["CategoryName"] as string;
```

and use the productname to get product details.

This way you can achieve better code inegrity with your logic and page that is being render. This is one of the new stuff in asp.net 4.0 for SEO.

You [can check](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) for better understanding.

Thanks